# Solidity: Storing and returning array in struct

Tags: solidity, brownie

Trying to store array directly in a struct however when I call the struct the array is not returned. Not sure whether this is just a return problem or a storage problem?

```
struct LockRoundData {
        uint256[] dates;
}
mapping(uint256 => LockRoundData) public lockRoundMapping;

function setLockRound(
        uint256[] _dates
) public {
        lockRoundMapping[0].dates = _dates;
}
```

Works completely fine for standard array variables.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this set an array of size 0. To store variables in the struct the size needs to be equal to what is stored.